# Creating an IUserSession that is used throughout my code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a bit of help on if I have coded this class correctly.

I want to handle the setting of client cookie/client store.

```
public class UserSession : IUserSession
{

    private readonly IReadOnlySession _repo;
    public UserSession(IReadOnlySession repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    private string _loginId;
    public string LoginID
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name; }
        set { _loginId = value; }
    }

    private string _companyIdentifier;
    public string CompanyIdentifier
    {
        get { return AuthenticateCookie.GetCompanyIdentifierFromTicket(LoginID); }
        set { _companyIdentifier = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// when the client store is set, this means the user has been changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="loginId"></param>
    /// <param name="identifier"></param>
    public void SetClientStore(string loginId, string identifier)
    {
        MyProfile = null;
        AuthenticateCookie.AddDetailsToCookie(loginId, identifier);

        LoginID = loginId;
        CompanyIdentifier = identifier;
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        // we could throw an exception here?
        MyProfile = null;
        HttpContext.Current.User = null;
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        //clear cookie values too?

    }

    private UserProfile _myprofile;
    public UserProfile MyProfile
    {
        get { return SetupProfile(); }
        private set { _myprofile = value; }
    }

    private UserProfile SetupProfile()
    {
        if (_myprofile == null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoginID) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(CompanyIdentifier))
            {
                Logout();
                return null;
            }

            //call repo to get object...

            _myprofile = _repo.All<User>()
                .Where(x => x.Login == LoginID)
                .Join(_repo.All<Profile>().Where(x => x.IsActive), 
                      x => x.UserID, y => y.UserID,
                      (x, y) =>
                          new
                            {
                                x.UserID, y.CompanyID, y.RoleID,
                            })
                .Join(_repo.All<Company>()
                        .Where(x => x.IsActive && x.Identifier == CompanyIdentifier),
                    x => x.CompanyID, y => y.CompanyID,
                    (x, y) =>
                        new
                          {
                              x.UserID, y.CompanyID, x.RoleID, x.IsSurveyor,
                              CompanyFriendlyName = y.Name,
                              CompanyType = y.Type
                          })
                .Join(_repo.All<Role>(), x => x.RoleID, y => y.RoleID,
                      (x, y) =>
                          new
                            {
                                x.UserID, x.CompanyID, y.RoleName, x.CompanyFriendlyName, x.CompanyType
                            })
                .Join(_repo.All<Subscription>(),
                      x => x.CompanyID, y => y.CompanyID,
                      (x, y) =>
                      new UserProfile
                          {
                              UserID = x.UserID,
                              CompanyID = x.CompanyID,
                              Role = x.RoleName.Convert<RoleName>(),
                              CompanyFriendlyName = x.CompanyFriendlyName,
                              LoginID = LoginID,
                              Identifier = CompanyIdentifier,
                              PricePlan = y.Name.Convert<PricePlanType>(),
                              CompanyType = x.CompanyType.Convert<CompanyType>()
                          })
                .SingleOrDefault();

            if (_myprofile == null)
                Logout();
        }

        return _myprofile;
    }
}
```

Comment: The Linq in SetupProfile is very confusing to understand as it is. I would really rather see that written in query syntax. Joins and groups using method syntax never make for readable code!

Answer (score 1):

It's great that you separated the ASP.NET specific implementation from the interface. Two things to watch:

1. Don't forget to call `Session.Abandon();Session.Clear();` in the `Logout` method.
2. `SetupProfile` contains a lot of code. This seems like business logic to me. Try to extract this code to its own class. An `IUserService` for instance. Or perhaps explicitly define [Query Objects](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).